# how to delete data that can restore again with delete status change in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to delete my form data but not permanently. i used delete status and i want to restore again in delete data.

this is my delete method. how can i use this method to update delete status.

```
public function destroy(Account $account)
{
    $findAccount = Account::find($account->id);

    if($findAccount->delete()){

        return redirect()->route('account.index')->with('success', 'Account details delete successfully!');
    }

    return back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Account details could not be deleted.');
}
```

Comment: use soft deleting (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure if it's clear to me, but I think you can use soft delete in your model. To do it, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting

You could add to your Account migration file:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

On your Account model file add:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Account extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    //your code

}
```

When you write your code, you can use the method `delete`. As below:

```
public function destroy(Account $account)
{
    $account = Account::withTrashed()->where('id', $account->id)->first();

    if ($account->trashed()) {
        $account->forceDelete(); //It will delete your data permanently (Just in case you wish to remove the row in your DB)
    } else {
        $account->delete(); //It will add a DateTime in the deleted_at column
    }
}

public function restore(Account $account)
{
    $account = Account::withTrashed()->where('id', $account->id)->first();

    if ($account->trashed()) {
        $account->restore(); //It will restore your data again (it means the deleted_at cell will be set NULL again)
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i created table column named status. i want to update that column value to 0 and show my data in views using this status. i view my data only column value 1. so i want to update my column value to zero and it stops showing that data in my view.

Answer (score 0):

use `SoftDelete`

How to use.. look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting

get all data with deleted data

```
Account::withTrashed()->get();
```

get all data without deleted data

```
Account::get();
```

restore all deleted data

```
Account::query()->restore();
```

EDIT

you are using status column right? 0 or 1.. need to display only 1 status..
like this..

all data

```
Account::all();
```

status 1

```
Account::where('status', true)->get();
```

restore 0 status => 1 status

```
Account::where('status', false)->update([
   'status' => true
]);
```

Comment: i created table column named status. i want to update that column value to 0 and show my data in views using this status. i view my data only column value 1. so i want to update my column value to zero and it stops showing that data in my view. when i want to restore that data simply change that status value.